# custom dimension value from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I was working on Google Anlytics Report and I was wondering how to get or return a query parameter value (not a dashboard, a single value based on the filter query) in JavaScript, like page view?

Relevant code:

```
var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
   query: { 
      dimension: 'ga:dimension1', 
      metrics: 'ga:pageview'
   },
   chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'Table',
      options: {
         width: '100%'
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: ga:pageview value for instance

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I was looking for a JavaScript code which returns the value of a page view (ga:pagevew, just the number) for one single certain custom dimension from GA.
For instance if I have the following Table ..

Custom Dimension              Page View
aaa                                      55
bbb                                      79

I want to return (have the value) the value of page view aaa.
If this is not clear enough please let me know.
Thanks Philip.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear at all. What have you tried, and what's not working? Do you currently have code that's getting a full result set and you just want a single value, or do you not have any code at all, and you're asking how to request data from the API?

Comment: @Philip
I have already built a JavaScript code which displays the whole table (I have a code that is getting a full result set) based on the Embed API, but I want a single value returned (pageview value) for some specific custom dimension I have.
Custom Dimension X .. PageView 55
I want to get 55 returned.
Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: I should not to have the whole table and don't need to, If it is possible you can help me in any possible way to get the value from the GA reports directly.

Comment: Please post the code you're currently using to display your table.

Comment: var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      dimension: 'ga:dimension1',
      metrics: 'ga:pageview'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'Table',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });
As I was saying I don't need the table if you think we can simply get the value from GA site directly using some query, am good with that.

The full code is found here.
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

Comment: @Philip Walton
If there is additional information you need I'm ready to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get data from a Google Analytics query, you should use the [`Data`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#data) object (which just runs a query) instead of the [`DataChart`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart) object (which runs a query and dumps the results into a Google Chart.

Both `Data` and `DataChart` objects emit events when their queries and come back successfully, so you just have to listen for those events, and log the results.

Here's an example:

```
// Creates a new report object.
var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
  query: {
    'ids': 'ga:XXXXXX',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
    'dimensions': 'ga:dimension1',
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
  }
});

// Runs the query.
report.execute();

// Specifies the callback function  to be run when the query succeeds.
report.on('success', function(response) {

  // Logs the entire response object.
  console.log(response);

  // Logs just the total pageviews.
  console.log(response.totalsForAllResults['ga:pageviews']);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I was trying to do ..
mainChart.on('success', function(response) {

        var dataTable = response.dataTable;
        var pageView = dataTable.getValue(0, 1);

        alert(pageView);

      });

What is the 'ids' though ?

Comment: You can look up the `ids` value(s) to use with the [Account Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/)

Comment: That helps me great, thanks. And. I added a filter parameter on the query to show me the result for a particular dimension (say dimension1 with value equal to A1), and it works perfect.
'filters': 'ga:dimension1==' + A1
But, what if I want to display the page view for each available dimension 1?

Comment: @AhaduMelesse if this answer helped you, then you should upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer. If you have additional questions you should start a new question, so other people with the same question can more easily find answers by searching.

Comment: It's very nice you mentioned this point. I thought this question is related with the starting question. And by the way, how can I upvote your answer, because I clicked the up-arrow and it did't change anything.
Thanks once again.

Comment: You need to have at least 15 reputation points to [up vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), but you should be able to [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) either way.

Comment: Done ! (Accepted the answer)
So, shall we proceed here for the second question or what do you think ?

Comment: Questions in comments is a bad practice. Please ask a new question.

Comment: I posted my question, and thank you so much for all your expertise answers and recommendations.